# How do I give access to SQL Server 2005 Reports for users outside domain without using FBA

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssrs

How do I give access to SQL Server 2005 Reports for users outside domain without using FBA.

I've built report using SSRS 2005 and published it on the report server.

The account is able to access the ASP.NET page which has the report control on it.

However the report area is inaccessible and gives 401 error for unauthenticated user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mo for the answer.

However, we got it fixed by giving access rights to sql server, report manager, report server and report directory to the asp.net application account.

Comment: Be really, really careful how much access rights you give.  If someone drops an aspx page in your web server that drops databases, and if you gave the asp.net account enough permissions, it'll happen.  This is hacker gold.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  in this case, the asp.net application by itself is an intranet application which requires password/usb smart card to log into.  but i would definitely want to look into the other options.

Answer (score 0):

We used NTLM proxy for this.

http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/

The developers did the most of it so I'm at a loss for details however.